# Problems setting up parseUser in android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm sure this is a stupid question but I'm attempting to test adding a test user with ParseUser. For some reason it is not being added to the server. Any help is appreciated. Sorry if this seem like an obvious thing but I've just started android programming.

Activity

```
public class SignupActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);

        final ParseUser currentUser = new ParseUser();


        currentUser.setUsername("Test");
        currentUser.setPassword("xxx");
        currentUser.setEmail("Test@aol.com");
        currentUser.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if (e == null){
                    Log.i("User added", "successful");
                }
            }
        });

}}
```

Application Class

```
public class MainApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();

        Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

        Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .applicationId("{I have actual app ID here}")
                .clientKey("{I have client key here}")
                .server("{It is here}")
                .build()
    );

        ParseObject parseObject = new ParseObject("FloridaLaw");


        ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
        defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
        defaultACL.setPublicWriteAccess(true);
        ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);



    }
}
```

PrintTrace

```
11-04 19:56:44.678 22669-22669/? I/zygote: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
11-04 19:56:44.718 22669-22669/? W/zygote: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
11-04 19:56:45.206 22669-22669/com.ronaldpitt.floridalaw I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
11-04 19:56:45.520 22669-22676/com.ronaldpitt.floridalaw I/zygote: Waiting for a blocking GC ObjectsAllocated
11-04 19:56:45.672 22669-22680/com.ronaldpitt.floridalaw I/zygote: Background concurrent copying GC freed 7395(2MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 59% free, 1051KB/2MB, paused 3.900ms total 182.247ms
11-04 19:56:45.677 22669-22676/com.ronaldpitt.floridalaw I/zygote: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 156.076ms for cause ObjectsAllocated
11-04 19:56:46.047 22669-22721/com.ronaldpitt.floridalaw I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
11-04 19:56:46.049 22669-22721/com.ronaldpitt.floridalaw W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you added your Application class `MainApplication.java` to the `AndroidManifest.xml`?

```
<application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  ...>
  ...
</application>
```

If not working try doing it directly in `AndroidManifest.xml` instead of Application class

```
<application ...>
  <meta-data
    android:name="com.parse.SERVER_URL"
    android:value="@string/parse_server_url" />
  <meta-data
    android:name="com.parse.APPLICATION_ID"
    android:value="@string/parse_app_id" />
  <meta-data
    android:name="com.parse.CLIENT_KEY"
    android:value="@string/parse_client_key"
  ...
</application>
```